# How can I call file using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am looking forward to call \File.txt using below AWS CLI , if you have exp please share it.

aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=network-interface.group-name,Values='\file.txt'  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Placement.AvailabilityZone, State.Name, InstanceId,Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value|[0]]'

File.txt includes Security Group Names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it, I'm assuming Security Group Name is on a separate line.

Command:

```
$(cat file.txt|sed 'N;s/\n/,/')
```

Input: file.txt:

```
cat file.txt
security-group-name-1
security-group-name-2
security-group-name-3
```

Output:

```
security-group-name-1,security-group-name-2
```

Full command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=network-interface.group-name,Values=$(cat file.txt|sed 'N;s/\n/,/') --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Placement.AvailabilityZone, State.Name, InstanceId,Tags[?Key==Name].Value|[0]]'
```

Comment: Could you say what this one will do?    (sed 'N;s/\n/,/')

Comment: replace new line with comma

Comment: $ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=network-interface.group-name,Values=$(cat file.txt|sed 'N;s/\n/,/') --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Placement.AvailabilityZone, State.Name, InstanceId,Tags[?Key==Name].Value|[0]]'
EMPTY Output

Comment: After that running the cmd as below, output is empty: aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=network-interface.group-name,Values=$(cat file.txt) --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Placement.AvailabilityZone, State.Name, InstanceId,Tags[?Key==Name].Value|[0]]'